# How to add EXTRA_CFLAGS to indigo eclipse cdt?

Tags: 10.04, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I used the instructions [here](https://www.ridgerun.com/developer/wiki/index.php/Eclipse_usage_with_RidgeRun_SDK) to install eclipse and the [here](https://www.ridgerun.com/developer/wiki/index.php/Debug_and_Profiling_Guide#Create_eclipse_project) to create an eclipse project but I suspect the instructions were written for an older version of eclipse. Specifically, there is no `Build (Incremental Build): build install EXTRA_CFLAGS+=-g...` in this version of eclipse. I have created the project without the EXTRA_CFLAGS and have been poking around in it looking for a place to add or set them. I see a number of things that look close in `Project Properties` but nothing that seems like a match.

Comment: Was there something else you were looking for in the answer?  Using `EXTRA_CFLAGS+=` is usually just a way to join the environment variables with more stuff.

Comment: I am not in the office today. I plan to work on this some more on Monday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not all one line item in eclipse...looking at your link it wants you to do something like this:

gcc -g EXTRA_CFLAGS+=-O0 EXTRA_CFLAGS+=-fno-omit-frame-pointer
Let's take that apart: `-g` Default debug level so
Project Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->Debugging and select Debug Level Default (-g)
[image]
`-O0` Optimization level so
Same tab Optimization None(-O0)
[image]
`-fno-omit-frame-pointer` so
Same tab Miscellaneous Other flags add `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`
[image]
You may or may not want to remove the other flags, but I wouldn't.
So you check in gcc c compiler and it looks like this
[image]
Apply and OK.
Repeat the same(disabling debug completely) for your release build.
Done and done.

Comment: No problem.  Glad it worked out for you.